# Regex, find pattern only in middle of string

Tags: python, regex

I am using python 2.6 and trying to find a bunch of repeating characters in a string, let's say a bunch of `n`'s, e.g. `nnnnnnnABCnnnnnnnnnDEF`. In any place of the string the number of `n`'s can be variable.

If I construct a regex like this:

`re.findall(r'^(((?i)n)\2{2,})', s)`,

I can find occurences of case-insensitive `n`'s only in the beginning of the string, which is fine. If I do it like this:

`re.findall(r'(((?i)n)\2{2,}$)', s)`,

I can detect the ones only in the end of the sequence. But what about just in the middle?

At first, I thought of using `re.findall(r'(((?i)n)\2{2,})', s)` and the two previous regex(-ices?) to check the length of the returned list and the presence of `n`'s either in the beginning or end of the string and make logical tests, but it became an ugly if-else mess very quickly.

Then, I tried `re.findall(r'(?!^)(((?i)n)\2{2,})', s)`, which seems to exlude the beginning just fine but `(?!$)` or `(?!\z)` at the end of the regex only excludes the last `n` in `ABCnnnn`. Finally, I tried `re.findall(r'(?!^)(((?i)n)\2{2,})\w+', s)` which seems to work sometimes, but I get weird results at others. It feels like I need a lookahead or lookbehind, but I can't wrap my head around them.

Comment: Try [`(?<!^)(?<!n)((n)\2{2,})(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/dY3cZ9/1). You do not need an inline case-insensitive modifier version `(?i)`, just use `re.I` (as the whole pattern will become case-insensitive anyway when you use `(?i)`).

Comment: what's wrong with `((?i)n)\1{2,}` https://regex101.com/r/oT6vZ1/1 ?

Comment: or `\B(?<!n)(n)\1{2,}\B(?!n)`

Comment: OK, to clarify in an example like this: `nnnABCnnnnDEFnnnnnGHInnnnnn`, I would like `re.findall` to return only `[('nnnn', 'n'), ('nnnnn','n')]`, so the stretches of n's in the middle.

Comment: Then use [`(?<!^)(?<!n)((n)\2{2,})(?!$)(?!n)`](https://regex101.com/r/dY3cZ9/2)

Comment: Is "n" a character or a subpattern?

Comment: @Wiktor, Yap! that does it! If you can elaborate a bit on the beginning and `(?<!^)(?<!n)` and `(?!n)` in the end, I will accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: No, `n` is a character, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a complicated regex in order to refuse of matching the leading and trailing `n` characters. As a more **pythonic** approach you can `strip()` your string then find all the sequence of `n`s using `re.findall()` and a simple regex:

```
>>> s = "nnnABCnnnnDEFnnnnnGHInnnnnn" 
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r'n{2,}', s.strip('n'), re.I)
['nnnn', 'nnnnn']
```

*Note* : `re.I` is *Ignore-case* flag which makes the regex engine matches upper case and lower case characters.

Comment: `n` is a sequence of characters. You will need to `re.sub` them  I guess.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't matter, `str.strip()` will remove all of the leading and trailing occurrences of passed argument.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it seems that `n` is a character, see the last comments.

Comment: Well, I understand, and I agree the best way is just matching `n{2,}` (or `n{3,}` I guess here) then with either "trimming" the resulting array or stripping the `n` symbols from the string.

Comment: @Kasramvd: What I meant is `strip("red")` will also strip "edr" and "der" from start and end of string. If `n` were not a single symbol, that would not work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. And the reason that I used this approach was be cause here we are just dealing with one kind of character. ;)

Comment: `[i for i in re.findall(r'^n+|n+$|(n{2,})', s, re.I) if i]`

Answer (score 2):

***NOTE***: **This solution assumes `n` may be a sequence of some characters. For more efficient alternatives when `n` is just 1 character, see other answers here.**

You can use

```
(?<!^)(?<!n)((n)\2{2,})(?!$)(?!n)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dY3cZ9/2)

The regex will match repeated consecutive `n`s (ignoring case can be achieved with `re.I` flag) that are not at the beginning (`(?<!^)`) or end (`(?!$)`) of the string and not before (`(?!n)`) or after (`(?<!n)`) another `n`.

The `(?<!^)(?<!n)` is a sequence of 2 lookbehinds: `(?<!^)` means *do not consume the next pattern if preceded with the start of the string*. The `(?<!n)` negative lookbehind means *do not consume the next pattern if preceded with `n`*. The negative lookaheads `(?!$)` and `(?!n)`have similar meanings: `(?!$)` fails a match if after the current position the end of string occurs and `(?!n)` will fail a match if `n` occurs after the current position in string (that is, right after matching all consecutive `n`s. The lookaround conditions must all be met, that is why we only get the innermost matches.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/x4mTUa):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<!^)(?<!n)((n)\2{2,})(?!$)(?!n)', re.IGNORECASE)
s = "nnnnnnnABCnnnnnNnnnnDEFnNn"
print([x.group() for x in p.finditer(s)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since "n" is a character (and not a subpattern), you can simply use:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=[^n])nn+(?=[^n])(?i)', s)
```

or better:

```
re.findall(r'n(?<=[^n]n)n+(?=[^n])(?i)', s)
```